# Access a URL and download a wav file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am new to java and javascript programing.

I was able to write a piece of code in java to access a particular URL and download the wav file from that URL (this url returns a wav file).

```
url = new URL('url name');
input = url.openStream();
output = new FileOutputStream (wavfile);

byte[] buffer = new byte[500];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}       
output.close();
```

I do not want to do this in Java and want to be able to do it in Javascript. The main attempt is to use javascript and get the wav file and play it on a HTML5 enabled browser.

I eventually want to put it on an android platform, so do not prefer to use ajax or jquery.

Please suggest how this can be done in javascript.

Thanks,
axs

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use JavaScript to read files but HTML5 has a **File API**, take a look at:

- http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/
- [READING FILES IN JAVASCRIPT USING THE FILE APIS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, the links are very useful. The concern is that I need to access the URL, then it will do some processing and then return a wav file. So, as a first step, I will have to access the URL, wait for the wav file to be ready and then download it. And after downloading it, to play the wav file. Please help me get these steps right. Thanks once again.

Comment: ok, say I want to access http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=30.223980,-97.77485000000001&sensor=false and get the JSON object into a file using javascript along, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function loadWavFromUrl(audioContext, url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await response.blob()
  const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  return await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
}
```

I recommend reusing `AudioContext` instances, which is why there is a param for it. You can call like this:

```
  const ac = new AudioContext();
  loadWavFromUrl(audioContext, url).then(audioBuffer => ...do stuff with it...);
```

The OP is maybe confused about reusing Javascript code in Java/Android. The code will be different.